# Electric field of transmission cable

Tags: power, electromagnetism, transmission-line

What will be the effect when an 132kv "Extra super voltage" cable is pulled inside a 300mm dia PE80 grade hdpe pipe and the pipe is warped by binding wire? Is there any problem with the field of 132kv line? The hdpe pipe is encased with concrete, steel is included in concrete.

Comment: To answer this question you need to specify all material properties including the dimensions. Thereafter it becomes a matter of calculation.

Comment: Do you mean "warped" or "wrapped"?

Comment: This is going to have to be experimentally verified as you are probably the first person to posit a question like this. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect I hope your not pulling this wire when its 'live'

Answer (score 1):

If the 132 kV cable is armored with steel or aluminium wires, the strong electric field exists only between the conductor in the center of the cable and the steel wires near the circumference of the cable. The steel wires are grounded and the insulation between the center and the shield is exposed to the complete potential difference between 132 kV and ground. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_cable for a cross section of such cables.